# What does "in one game" / "in one round" means in Zombie Gunship achievements?

Tags: zombie-gunship

What does "in one game", for example

> Fire 300 consecutive rounds of the 40mm in one game.

and "in one round", for example

> Fire 1000 25mm bullets without overheating in one round.

mean in objectives / achievements in **Zombie Gunship** mobile game by [Limbic Software](http://www.limbic.com/ourgames.html) for iOS and Android (was in Humble Bundle).

I cannot pass those objectives...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both mean in one game. There are no rounds in Zombie Gunship, so the use of that word in your second achievement is a misnomer and likely a typo on their side.

I've achieved both of these, so I'm certain it's possible and within the confines of a single game up to the point of the game's termination.

The first achievement requires you to fire the 40mm 300 times without firing any other gun between shots.

The second achievement simply takes time because of the high count of 1000, and, since there's no in-game counter, it can be difficult to judge how many you've unloaded. A single overheat will at the very least reset your count, perhaps even disqualify that game.

*Edit:*

For the second one, just make sure you're constantly firing the 25mm right from the start of the game... even while you're moving around looking for zombies. Fully upgrading the cooling and rate of fire for that gun obviously helps with this achievement.

Answer (score 0):

Re: the 25mm... I suggest maximizing the cooling rate, but do NOT max the firing rate... If the firing fate of the 25mm is too high, it becomes much harder to use it vs. zombies which are attacking humans. For the same reason, I highly recommend that you do not fully upgrade the 25mm's "Damage Radius" (which increases the spread of fired rounds)!

Note that as you fire the 25mm, the "crosshair box" gets bigger, and when you stop, it shrinks back to its normal size. If the box grows to a certain size, the gun overheats, and goes into "cooldown mode". Upgrading "Faster firing" will increase the rate at which the "crosshair box" grows, whereas increasing "Faster Cooling" both slows the rate of growth AND increases the rate of cooling if you stop firing. Upgrades in both areas are necessary to complete Objectives such as "Fire _____ 25mm rounds without overheating" (IMO).

Side note re: the 25mm... I've recently discovered that it works wonders on the large zombies! :-)